# How to interact with div using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to use keyboard shortcuts to manipulate divs, I am developing a project for **use with seniors** and they **not interact with mouse**, can I use keyboard shortcuts to click on the divs and open their contents?

How to use the event `trigger` as long as the keys are pressed?

```
keydown = ctrl+g
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 alert alert-danger"><a href="">Open ctrl+g or click</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 alert alert-warning"><a href="">Open ctrl+d or click</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 alert alert-success"><a href="">Open ctrl+e or click</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 alert alert-info"><a href="">Open ctrl+i or click</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

> Can this impact browser shortcuts?

Example `ctrl+g` impact from google-chrome, not open a link, open to search console of browser

> Or is there another form of accessibility use?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: you can simply use $("#div").keyup(function(e){ if(e.target == 13) alert("this is enter");}) and listen to what shortcut you want. is this what you meant in your question

Comment: I do not know how to use it without disturbing browser shortcuts.

Comment: @msoliman yes. correct

Comment: @VMomesso I can post it as an answer if it helped you

Comment: @msoliman Yes it will help me a lot, but do you know another form of accessibility better?

Comment: @VMomesso what you mean by better form of accessibility? plz clarify more to better understand

Comment: the site will be used by the elderly and not use the mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `keyup` event and listen to any shortcut you want.

```
$("#div").keyup(function(e){ 
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'g') { //could be anything 13 for example
    alert("this is test");
});
```

Note this event handler I wrote for only div actions if you want to add for the whole page you can use `$(document)`

Comment: Doing it on `document` is a must-do because this will never trigger on the targeted div if there is no inputs in it

Comment: @Plotisateur yes you're right however I wrote it as the question mentioned to be on a div which means it has some controls. thanks for the note through appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `keyup` event:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'g') {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $output = $('<span/>').text('You typed ctrl+g.');
      $('body').append($output).append('<br/>');
    }
  });
});
```

As for interfering with browser keyboard shortcuts -- that's possible in some cases. You can just design your shortcuts around it (`Ctrl+Shift`, etc).

For your use case, you'd just replace the code within `if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'g') {...}` to select the appropriate `<div>` and expand it.